# change buttons color on finger move In Gridlayout?

Tags: android

I need to change the color of my buttons on finger move which is in the Grid layout. On touch button change color is working but on the finger, the move is not working. Can anyone help me?

**Here is my Activity**

```
public class Layoutactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout ln1;
    android.widget.GridLayout myGridLayout;
    demoview[] myViews;
    demoview tView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layoutactivity);

        myGridLayout = (android.widget.GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygrid);
        int numOfCol = myGridLayout.getColumnCount();
        int numOfRow = myGridLayout.getRowCount();
        myViews = new demoview[numOfCol*numOfRow];


        for(int yPos=0; yPos<numOfRow; yPos++){
            for(int xPos=0; xPos<numOfCol; xPos++){
                tView = new demoview(this, xPos, yPos,yPos);
                tView.setId(yPos);
                // tView.setOnToggledListener(this);
                myViews[yPos*numOfCol + xPos] = tView;
                //   myGridLayout.addView(tView);
                myGridLayout.addView(tView,yPos);
            }
        }
        myGridLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                final float X =  event.getRawX();
                final float Y =  event.getRawY();
                Log.d("Rowcordinate",""+X+" @#%$ " + Y);
                return true;
            }
        });


        myGridLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {

                        final int MARGIN = 5;

                        int pWidth = myGridLayout.getWidth();
                        int pHeight = myGridLayout.getHeight();
                        int numOfCol = myGridLayout.getColumnCount();
                        int numOfRow = myGridLayout.getRowCount();
                        int w = pWidth/numOfCol;
                        int h = pHeight/numOfRow;

                        for(int yPos=0; yPos<numOfRow; yPos++){
                            for(int xPos=0; xPos<numOfCol; xPos++){
                                android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams params =
                                        (GridLayout.LayoutParams)myViews[yPos*numOfCol + xPos].getLayoutParams();
                                params.width = w - 2*MARGIN;
                                params.height = h - 2*MARGIN;
                                params.setMargins(MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
                                myViews[yPos*numOfCol + xPos].setLayoutParams(params);
                            }
                        }

                    }});
    }
    public class MyGridLayout extends GridLayout {
        public MyGridLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);

                Log.d("childid",""+getChildCount());
                try {
                    child.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**Here is my custom view code:**

```
public class demoview extends View {

    int idX = 0; //default
    int idY = 0;
    //default
    int iview = 0;

    public demoview(Context context, int x, int y,int vid) {
        super(context);
        idX = x;
        idY = y;
        iview=vid;

       // init();
    }

    public demoview(Context context) {
        super(context);
       // init();
    }

    public demoview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        //init();
    }

    public demoview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
      //  init();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
                MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public int getIdX(){
        return idX;
    }

    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return super.getX();
    }

    @Override
    public float getY() {
        return super.getY();
    }

    public int getIview() {
        return iview;
    }

    public int getIdY(){
        return idY;
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: I am not able to share the code now i will share tomorrow morning But any suggestion u have?
on finger move how can we change color of views.

Answer (score 0):

you can Override OnTouchEvent and than check all it's child's coordinate

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if (gridLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof Button) {
                        Rect rect = new Rect();
                        gridLayout.getChildAt(i).getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
                        if (rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
                            Button btn = (Button) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
                            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```